# Filtering a list based on a dictionary in a fastest way

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, filter, hashset

I am stuck with the performance of the filtering operation of a list based on a Dictionary and need help in identifying the fastest way to do that.

I have a list(also tried Hashset and Dictionary) of strings which I need to filter out based on the values of another data structure Dictionary in this case. I need all the values which are not in the Dictionary. List count is nearby 300000 and the Dictionary count is 200000. When I am using the following code it is taking a hell lot of time. Please provide your inputs how can I improve this operation.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictLocalFile - this has around 200000 entries.

var finalFilesHashSet = 
    new HashSet<string>(
        FinalFilesList
       .Where(x => !dictLocalFile.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(Path.GetFileName(x)))));
```

Comment: Profile your application.

Comment: You probably want to cache the result of `Path.GetFileName(x)` for each item in the dictionary ahead of time.  String manipulation can be somewhat slow

Comment: @MickyD Cannot do that as I need the filepaths as result of filtering.

Comment: From my experience lambda expressions are slow as hell. Same with the where function. Suggestion : if you really need performance use the good old for loop (not foreach, it is slow too). And profiling your program is a good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using dictionary efficiently. You want to check if dictionary does not contain key. Change your code to use `.ContainsKey` method. Also you should probably invoke Path.GetFileName(x) in advance out of that loop and measure what is its impact.

```
var finalFilesHashSet = new HashSet<string>(
    FinalFilesList.Where(x => !dictLocalFile.ContainsKey(Path.GetFileName(x))));
```

With dictionary code you wrote basically eliminate all performance advantages dictionary gives you: O(1) get operations. Instead you convert it to enumerable and iterate through dictionary content. Built-in method is essentially a hash table lookup

Comment: Earlier I tried this as well however no improvement in performance. Cannot make Path.GetFileName(x) as separate list as I need the filepath as output of the operation.

Comment: Maybe you've done something wrong, because `.ContainsKey()` should be O(1) while your loop is O(N). With Path.GetFileName you can do `var intermediateList = FinalFilesList.Select(file => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();`  If you can prepare reproducible example of slowness, I can take a look with profiler.